# AD - What is the meaning of the "Pwd-last-set" attribute for a Windows Server?

Tags: server, active-directory, change-password

This question follows an audit on my AD where Windows servers with very old **PasswordLastSet** attributes have been discovered.

I'm familiar with using the Pwd-last-set attribute in order to check when an AD user has last changed his password. But what does this attribute mean when talking about a computer-type object like a laptop or a windows server ?

The Microsoft documentation states it is *"The date and time that the password for this account was last changed"*. I don't think this means the local administrator of the computer, since I've clearly not changed mine at the date my Pwd-last-set attribute indicates.

Finally, if it isn't the local administrator nor my account, how can I **set a new password** that will refresh the attribute ?

**EDIT**
So the password is actually the Machine Account password used for communication between the computer/server and the DC
It's supposed to be renewed every 30 days on default Windows settings through the following registery key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters

I still don't have a way to easily force the renew of this password but found some leads :

- Put the MaximumPasswordAge in the registery to a low number and restart the machine
- Use the "Reset Account" options when right-clicking the object in the active directory -> What are the consequences for a server ?
- Use the Reset-ComputerMachinePassword Powershell command -> What are the consequences for a server ?

Comment: You should also investigate and change when needed properties `PasswordNeverExpires` and `PasswordNotRequired` (both Boolean). This can explain why you are seeing very old PasswordLastSet attributes.

Comment: If you reset a computer's password, it will no longer be able to communicate with the domain and most probably you would need to rejoin it manually.